# Pulling remote repository on Artifact Registry fails with Internal Server Error 500

Tags: google-artifact-registry, remote-repository

English is not my first language so I'm sorry if I couldnt describe whats going on exactly.
Currently, Im planning to setup remote repository on arfifact registry for this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/flowingspdg/csgo-get5-docker-dev .
So I set up remote repository on asia-northeast1, tried to pull it with docker but it failed with Internal Server Error 500.

I understand that remote repository is in preview, but I was wondering if anybody having same issue as I do.
Thank you.

I'm working on Container Optimized OS.
Set up access token for asia-docker.pkg.dev : (oauth2 access token can be generated on Cloud Shell(`gcloud auth print-access-token`).

```
docker login -u oauth2accesstoken https://asia-docker.pkg.dev
```

Tried to pull image on remote repository:

```
ruk1ium@instance-1 ~ $ docker pull asia-docker.pkg.dev/got5-90e88/get5loader-srcds-image-proxy-asia/flowingspdg/csgo-get5-docker-dev
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from got5-90e88/get5loader-srcds-image-proxy-asia/flowingspdg/csgo-get5-docker-dev
ddade83992f9: Pull complete 
022fec5bfa78: Pull complete 
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete 
07700b897eec: Pull complete 
1a5dc8d59e92: Pull complete 
91c0dab035b5: Pull complete 
799c4dc35eec: Pull complete 
4993168e1df0: Retrying in 1 second 
0db1ca3b5cf0: Download complete 
ea7588ae7c66: Download complete 
d7efbccded20: Download complete
```

it shows `Retrying in 1 second`  in log but actually it fails eventually.

It works when I try pulling same image on standard repository so I doubt its remote repository's issue.

Answer (score 0):

We've made some improvements to the error handling for remote repos recently. If you try again, it may give a more useful error